# Can't use non-standard search engines in firefox widget on android

Tags: android-widget, firefox-android

I asked this question in the support forum for firefox on android more than three weeks ago (https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1167806), but haven't gotten any reactions, but the counter (I'm not sure how precise/easy to manipulate that is) suggests that it might not just be me.

I've added the Firefox widget to my home screen on my new android phone, but if I select any of the search engines I've added (DuckDuckGo, Qwant or English wikipedia) as my default search engine in Firefox, the search feature of the widget doesn't work. It displays the usual page with an input field at the top, with a magnifying glass on the left, but there's no grey text saying which search engine will be used and no icon showing it. And entering anything only open a list of previous searches, but pressing the magnifying glass (the enter key of the on screen keyboard displays a magnifying glass in this case) gives no result..

If I select Google (I won't use that), Twitter, Amazon or "Wikipedia (da)" which were there from the start (I guess Firefox have registered that I've select Danish as language in the phone, and added "Wikipedia (da)" based one that, and that indicates that there is some support for adding search engines), they seem to work, but none of those are good for the type of searches I normally perform).

What can I do? I've swiped "Firefox" and "Firefox search" off the list of recently used apps between starts of Firefox to select default search engine and starts of the widget to make sure they weren't running and used some cached values.

Since then I've rebooted the phone on several occasions, with DuckDuckGo selected as default search engine in settings, and the result of launching a search from the widget is the same, so it seems this is not just a matter of getting Firefox restarted properly.

Answer (score 0):

The widget is broken and won't be fixed it seems https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1131087